# HBase filtering non-empty strings

Tags: java, api, hbase

I have an HBase table with 'a' and 'b' column families. Every row has at least one column in family 'a', but may not have any columns in family 'b'. How can I select only rows that do not contain columns in 'b' family? (I'm using HBase Java API)

Answer (score 0):

To scan everything for each row and a particular column family, instantiate a Scan object like shown below.

```
Scan scan = new Scan(); //creating a scan object for all rows.

scan.addFamily(byte[] column_family); // adding your required column family to scan object.

ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);

for (Result result : scanner) {
// .......
}
```